# Python script to automatically change crontab startup on raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, cron, raspberry-pi3

Looking for some recommendations to coding a python script that will edit the crontab file to make a file boot automatically. I already have it working through command line, but I'm trying to automate the process to simplify re-programming multiple pi's.

Currently I'm using os.system() to open the file, but now need to add, "@reboot sh /home/pi/epaperHat/RaspberryPi/machine/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1" at the end.

```py
import os
from time import sleep

os.system("chmod 755 launcher.sh")
sleep(0.5)
os.system("cd")
os.system("mkdir logs")
sleep(0.1)
os.system("sudo crontab -e")
sleep(0.1)
```

Ideally, I run this file then the raspberry pi reboots and runs launcher.sh shell.